# x86 assembly syntax check

Tags: assembly, syntax, x86

We have an exam this coming week on x86 assembly and this segment of code confuses me a lot in the syntax check.

what does byte ptr, word ptr and etc means in x86 assembly?

for example `NEG byte ptr [si]` or `NEG word ptr [si]` I know that these two are valid syntax at x86 assembly but why `NEG byte ptr si` and `NEG word ptr si` are not valid?

Comment: Well, probably because `byte ptr` and `word ptr` mean pointer, so you need to provide pointers after them. Try to compile this to get error description from Assembler itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`[si]` is a memory operand, i.e. some data located in memory at the address specified by `ds:si`. If you just say `NEG [si]` the assembler won't be able to tell whether you want to negate a byte in memory, or a word (or a dword..).

Hence you use `byte/word/dword ptr` to disambiguate between different possible instruction encodings. For example, with `NEG byte ptr [si]` you tell the assembler that you want it to generate the machine code sequence that will negate the byte located in memory at `ds:si`.

`NEG si` on the other hand operates directly on the register `si`, not on memory. Since the size of `si` is known (it's 16 bits), there's no point in you specifying the size of the operand.

Comment: For Intel syntax, you also use these when the operand size would not be known due to register(s) used in an instruction or the instruction type. An example of a non-pointer usage would be push byte ptr 012h, or push word ptr 01234h, which in these cases the operands are immediate values but the byte ptr and/or word ptr prefixes are needed to know the operand size.